# Flutter Expansion Tile -- Header Color Change, and Trailing Animated Arrow Color Change

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I have used the Expansion Tile to generate a Expansion List View.
I'm facing some customization issues in Expansion Tile Header.

Below is my code.

```
ExpansionTile(           
    title: Container(
        child: Text(
            getCategory(i),
            style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            ),
        ),
        color: Colors.black
    ),

    children: <Widget>[
        new Container(
            height: 60.0,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top:10.0, left: 10.0, right:10.0, bottom: 10.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(                    
            color: Colors.blue,
            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(  Radius.circular(5.0) ),
            ),
        ),
        new Container(
            height: 60.0,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top:10.0, left: 10.0, right:10.0, bottom: 0.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(                    
            color: Colors.green,
            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(  Radius.circular(5.0) ),
            ),
        )
    ],
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
)
```

I'm getting below result.

[image]

What I'm expecting to have is below.

[image]

If anyone know a workaround to customize the header color, please advice.

Comment: Already answered on https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24917

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks a lot for your support on this. I'll try this out.

Comment: @Buddhika I added my answer from github :).

Comment: Thanks @diegoveloper. I tried this out and jt works as expected. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you check the source code of the ExpansionTitle , you will notice that the header item is a ListTile , so you can't change the background because it hasn't a parent with a color property.
I modified a little the class to support what you need.

Add this file to your project: https://gist.github.com/diegoveloper/02424eebd4d6e06ae649b31e4ebcf53c

And import like this way to avoid conflicts because the same name.

```
    import 'package:nameofyourapp/custom_expansion_tile.dart' as custom;
```

I put an alias 'custom' but you can change for any alias.

Usage:

```
    custom.ExpansionTile(
              headerBackgroundColor: Colors.black,
              iconColor: Colors.white,
              title: Container(
              ...
```

Remember, Flutter has a lot of Widgets out of the box, but If any of them don't fit what you need, you'll have to check the source code and create your own widget.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This dolved my problem.

Comment: How to do the same thing with a background image of `headerBuilder` of `expansionPanel`?

Answer (score 13):

In my opinion, the more preferable way is wrap It with a new `Theme`, so It could work as expected:

```
Theme(
  data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(accentColor: ColorPalette.fontColor, unselectedWidgetColor:  ColorPalette.fontColor..withOpacity(0.8)),
  child: ListView(
    children: <Widget>[
      ExpansionTile(
        title: Text("Padding"),
        children: <Widget>[
          Text("Left"),
          Text("Top"),
          Text("Right"),
          Text("Bottom"),
        ],
      )
    ],
  ),
)
```

Instead of copy a full class to customize, check the source code, you could find more `Theme` attribute to override.

```
    _borderColorTween
      ..end = theme.dividerColor;
    _headerColorTween
      ..begin = theme.textTheme.subhead.color
      ..end = theme.accentColor;
    _iconColorTween
      ..begin = theme.unselectedWidgetColor
      ..end = theme.accentColor;
    _backgroundColorTween
      ..end = widget.backgroundColor;
```

If you want a more animatable widget or something, I would recommend diegoveloper's answer. Otherwise, just wrap It with `Theme`, so you won't need to maintain the Component, and get native flutter component.

Answer (score 13):

A much easier way than all of those suggested is to wrap your ExpansionTile in a [ListTileTheme](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTileTheme-class.html).

Once you do this, you can change the backgroundColor to whatever you'd like. In my case, I've done the same thing with the ListTiles inside of the ExpansionTile so that the header can have one color and the children can have another color.

```
return ListTileTheme(
                  tileColor: Colors.grey.shade300,
                  child: ExpansionTile(
                    leading: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:4.0),
                      child: Text('Outer Tile'),
                    ),
                    title: null,
                    children: [
                      Slidable(
                        actionPane: SlidableDrawerActionPane(),
                        child: ListTileTheme(
                          tileColor: Colors.white,
                          child: ListTile(
                            title: Text('Inner Tile'),
                            subtitle: Text('subtitle'),
                            leading: FlutterLogo(),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                );
```

[image]

I think this is easier than digging through the docs to find which Theme elements correspond to individual ListTile parameters.

Comment: best answer so far

Comment: how did you change arrow color

Answer (score 4):

It seems the ExpansionTile was changed and you can now directly configure lots of colors. As an example, for the arrows:

```dart
    return ExpansionTile(
      // sets the color of the arrow when collapsed
      collapsedIconColor: Colors.red,
      // sets the color of the arrow when expanded
      iconColor: Colors.green,
    );
```

Answer (score 3):

I think better this solution more than custom list tile .

```
  Widget customTheme(Widget child, BuildContext context) => Theme(
    data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
        dividerColor: Colors.transparent,
        dividerTheme: DividerThemeData(
            color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background)),
    child: child,
  );
```

[Code Gist](https://gist.github.com/VB10/491dd6833744b7d543c2c9627034e01a)
[image]

Answer (score 2):

For changing trailing arrow icon color you can wrap expansion tile with Theme and make theme light and set accet color and primary color to dark and it will work.

```
return Theme(
            data: ThemeData.light()
                .copyWith(accentColor: darkAccent, primaryColor: darkAccent),
            child: ExpansionTile(
              title: Text(
                data['number'],
                style:
                    TextStyle(color: darkAccent, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option which should work is wrapping both the entire expansion tile and each individual container in a Card() widget as they have a color property. The downside is that the background for your expansion will be colored as well as the title, but if you set a color for the child cards, they will not be affected by the parent an so they could be individually colored as you like.

Answer (score 0):

I use this great little plugin, much more flexible than the Flutter Material. You can change the background and borders and have custom icons for open and close states. https://pub.dev/packages/configurable_expansion_tile

Answer (score 0):

For trouble with the arrow color: notice it's an `ExpandIcon`, defined as a [local `Widget expandIconContainer`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/expansion_panel.dart#L500) in `_ExpansionPanelListState.build()`.

When your `ExpansionPanel` uses `canTapOnHeader: true`, you get `ExpandIcon(onPressed: null)`, so the color used for the [underlying `IconButton`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/expand_icon.dart#L175) is determined by `Theme#disabledColor`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `ExpansionTileTheme`

```
ExpansionTileTheme(
     data: ExpansionTileThemeData(
       collapsedIconColor: MyColor,//This property is for collapsed arrow
     ),
     child: ExpansionTile(),
)
```